# Request quits unresponsive when trying to assign value to a string using Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, dapper

I'm using Dapper to make queries in my database. And in one of those queries I have a result that I was not expecting, and without any error message.

What happens is that I am making a request request from Postman, and this request reaches my WebAPI, but I do not get a response and the request closes.

Debugging the code I got into the method where I do the SQL query using Dapper, and when trying to assign value to the string field the application simply gives dispose in all classes without displaying error messages.

Below is my code:

```
private async Task<ClassificacaoRiscoModelRequest> ObterClassificacaoRisco(string protocolo)
    {
        string query = $@"SELECT
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'neoplasia' AS neoplasia,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'escalaGlasgow' AS escalaGlasgow,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'outrasDoencas' AS outrasDoencas,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'temNefropatia' AS temNefropatia,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'aberturaOcular' AS aberturaOcular,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'outrosDetalhes' AS outrosDetalhes,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'queixaPaciente' AS queixaPaciente,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'respostaMotora' AS respostaMotora,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'repostaVerbal' AS repostaVerbal,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'temOutrasDoencas' AS temOutrasDoencas,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'resultadoEscalaComa' AS resultadoEscalaComa,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'temDiabetesPaciente' AS temDiabetesPaciente,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'corClassificacaoRisco' AS corClassificacaoRisco,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'temDoencaRespiratoria' AS temDoencaRespiratoria,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'temCardiopatiaPaciente' AS temCardiopatiaPaciente,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'temHipertensaoPaciente' AS temHipertensaoPaciente,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'medicamentoEmUsoPaciente' AS medicamentoEmUsoPaciente,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'escalaGlasgowJustificativa' AS escalaGlasgowJustificativa,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'medicamentoEmUsoPacienteDetalhes' AS medicamentoEmUsoPacienteDetalhes,
                            tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'cboDesc' AS cboDesc,
                            tbResult.conteudoUsuario ->> 'cpf' AS Cpf,
                            tbResult.conteudoUsuario ->> 'nome' AS Nome,
                            tbResult.conteudoEspecialidade AS nomeEspecialidade,
                            tbCausaExterna.c007_conteudo ->> 'nome' AS nomecausaexterna,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'htg' AS htg,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'sato' AS sato,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'pulso' AS pulso,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'alergia' AS alergia,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'pressaoArt' AS pressaoArt,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'temperatura' AS temperatura,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'pesoAproximado' AS pesoAproximado,
                            tbAvaliacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'alergiaDetalhes' AS alergiaDetalhes,
                            tbResult.datacriacao AS dataCriacao
                        FROM
                            (
                        SELECT
                            tbClassificacao.c007_conteudo - 'guidUsuario' - 'Especialidade' - 'Protocolo' AS conteudoClassificacao,
                            tbUsuario.c007_conteudo AS conteudoUsuario,
                            tbEspecialidade.c007_conteudo ->> 'nome' AS conteudoEspecialidade,
                            tbClassificacao.datacriacao 
                        FROM
                            PUBLIC.tb007_conteudodado AS protocolo
                            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            ( classificacao.c007_conteudo -> 'Protocolo' ->> 'c007_id' ) :: UUID AS idProtocolo,
                            classificacao.c007_conteudo,
                            classificacao.c007_datacriacao AS datacriacao 
                        FROM
                            PUBLIC.tb007_conteudodado AS classificacao 
                        WHERE
                            classificacao.c047_id :: TEXT = ANY (
                        VALUES
                            ( '79628e0d-6654-41f9-a50c-44da64c885e6' ))) tbClassificacao ON tbClassificacao.idProtocolo = protocolo.c007_id
                            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            row_to_json ( r ) AS c007_conteudo 
                        FROM
                            (
                        SELECT
                            usuario.c022_id AS c007_id,
                            usuario.c022_cpf AS cpf,
                            usuario.c022_nome AS nome 
                        FROM
                            PUBLIC.tb022_usuario AS usuario 
                        WHERE
                            c022_ativo = TRUE 
                            ) r 
                            ) tbUsuario ON tbUsuario.c007_conteudo ->> 'c007_id' = ANY (
                        VALUES
                            ( tbClassificacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'guidUsuario' ))
                            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            especialidade.c007_id,
                            especialidade.c007_conteudo 
                        FROM
                            PUBLIC.tb007_conteudodado AS especialidade 
                        WHERE
                            especialidade.c047_id :: TEXT = ANY (
                        VALUES
                            ( 'a1ee6e41-5b68-4c06-81b0-ec2bfe2186ec' ))) tbEspecialidade ON tbEspecialidade.c007_id :: TEXT = ( tbClassificacao.c007_conteudo ->> 'Especialidade' ) :: JSONB ->> 'c007_id' 
                        WHERE
                            protocolo.c007_id :: TEXT = ANY (
                        VALUES
                            ( '{protocolo}' ))) tbResult
                        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            causaexterna.c007_id,
                            causaexterna.c007_conteudo 
                        FROM
                            PUBLIC.tb007_conteudodado AS causaexterna 
                        WHERE
                            causaexterna.c047_id :: TEXT = ANY (
                        VALUES
                            ( '3cd7c000-1ef9-480a-bc17-6ce0aa662dcd' ))) tbCausaExterna ON tbCausaExterna.c007_id :: TEXT = ( tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'CausaExterna' ) :: JSONB ->> 'c007_id'
                            INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            avaliacao.c007_id,
                            avaliacao.c007_conteudo 
                        FROM
                            PUBLIC.tb007_conteudodado AS avaliacao 
                        WHERE
                            avaliacao.c047_id :: TEXT = ANY (
                        VALUES
                            ( '680c86c0-b78e-4ae5-93ff-288e26590cc0' ))) tbAvaliacao ON tbAvaliacao.c007_id :: TEXT = ( tbResult.conteudoClassificacao ->> 'Avaliacao' ) :: JSONB ->> 'c007_id' 
                        ORDER BY
                            tbResult.datacriacao DESC";

        var conteudoClassificacaoRisco = await _connection.QueryAsync<ClassificacaoRiscoModelRequest>(query);

        return conteudoClassificacaoRisco.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The template class I am using to extract the information is drawn as follows:

```
public class ClassificacaoRiscoModelRequest : BaseModelRequest
{

    public string NomeEspecialidade { get; set; }
    public string NomeCausaExterna { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

    //Conteudo Classificação
    public bool EscalaGlasgow { get; set; }
    public bool TemNefropatia { get; set; }
    public bool TemOutrasDoencas { get; set; }
    public bool TemDiabetesPaciente { get; set; }
    public bool TemDoencaRespiratoria { get; set; }
    public bool TemCardiopatiaPaciente { get; set; }
    public bool TemHipertensaoPaciente { get; set; }
    public bool MedicamentoEmUsoPaciente { get; set; }

    public string CboDesc { get; set; }
    public string Neoplasia { get; set; }
    public string OutrasDoencas { get; set; }
    public string AberturaOcular { get; set; }
    public string OutrosDetalhes { get; set; }
    public string QueixaPaciente { get; set; }
    public string RespostaMotora { get; set; }
    public string RespostaVerbal { get; set; }
    public string ResultadoEscalaComa { get; set; }
    public string CorClassificacaoRisco { get; set; }
    public string EscalaGlasgowJustificativa { get; set; }
    public string MedicamentoEmUsoPacienteDetalhes { get; set; }

    //Conteudo Usuário
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //Conteudo Avaliação
    public string Htg { get; set; }
    public string Sato { get; set; }
    public string Pulso { get; set; }
    public bool Alergia { get; set; }
    public string PressaoArt { get; set; }
    public string Temperatura { get; set; }
    public string PesoAproximado { get; set; }
    public string AlergiaDetalhes { get; set; }
}
```

Exactly when it arrives in the SET method of the property "CorClassificacaoRisco" the application simply exits from debug mode and I get no response from my request.

If anyone knows what it is or has already experienced this problem, please introduce me to the solution.

Comment: What database are you using? Does the query run successfully if you run it straight against the database (outside of C#)?

Comment: @mjwills I'm using PostgreSQL. And yes, this same query works perfectly when executed directly in the database (using pgAdmin or Navicat). There is also a detail that other queries work perfectly even from C # with Dapper.

Comment: @AlissonBoucinhas *"I'm using PostgreSQL"* then [edit] your question to add that tag.

Comment: I'd suspect that an exception is being thrown and is going uncaught on a background thread. Make sure you have exception logging in place, and check it works by intentionally adding a `throw new Exception();` into your code.

Comment: @Richardissimo As you advised, I placed the code in a try - catch block and managed to catch an exception that was not really appearing in the log. The problem really was not PostgreSQL, but I already figured out the problem. Thank you for alerting me about the possible exception.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tip of Richardissimo I was able to catch the exception by placing the database access code with Dapper within a try-catch block. The error was caused by a value saved in the database that should be boolean but had no information (true / false). When Dapper tried to assign value to a variable that was declared as Boolean in the class an exception was thrown.